# Approximating pi in Perl - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: perl, math, logic

I am trying to approximate pi using the [Ramanujan algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Miscellaneous_approximations):

[image: Approximations of pi]

It should compute the sums until the last sum is less than `1e-15`.

This was just supposed to be for fun and occupy at most half an hour of my time... but my code is not producing anything close to pi and I'm not sure why. Quite possibly something silly that I've overlooked, but not sure!

Just a note: I'm starting `$k` at 1 because 0 breaks my `factorial`sub and from my calculations k=0 would return 0 anyway.

I realise the code can be more efficiently written; I wrote it out as simply as possible to see if I could understand where I was going wrong. Any help appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub approx_pi {
    my $const = (2 * sqrt(2)) / 9801;

    my $k = 1;
    my $sum = 0;
    while ($sum < 1e-15) {
        my $p1 = factorial((4 * $k), 1);
        my $p2 = 1103 + (26390 * $k);
        my $p3 = (factorial($k, 1))**4;
        my $p4 = 396**(4 * $k);

        $sum = $sum + ( ($p1 * $p2) / ($p3 * $p4) );

        $k++;
    }

    #print "Const: $const\nSum: $sum\n";
    return (1 / ($const * $sum));
}

sub factorial {
    my ($i, $total) = @_;
    return $total if $i == 1;

    $total = $total * $i;
    #print "i: $i total: $total\n";

    factorial($i-1, $total);
}

my $pi = approx_pi();
print "my pi is: $pi\n";
```

Comment: "from my calculations k=0 would return 0 anyway. " - talk us through that?

Comment: put k = 0 into the equation and you end up with a numerator zero at least. I'm not sure about k!, I read that if k=0 then k!=1 (somehow) but if the numerator is 0, then the result is zero. Unless my basic mathematics is incorrect....

Comment: oh shoot, what is k! if k = 0 ??

Comment: .... scrap that, that is the problem.... thanks @AakashM. A bad assumption

Comment: No problem. Bear in mind that mathematicians are intensely concise and if the `k = 0` term weren't needed, the formula **would definitely** be "Sum from `k = 1` to `infinity`"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATED**

There are several problems with the script.

if `k==0` then the item is `1103`. So start `$k` from 0, not 1. For this You should modify `factorial`:

```
sub factorial {
    my ($i, $total) = @_;
    return $total if $i <= 1;
```

There is no need to pass the product in factorial. It could be something like this:

```
sub fact {
  my $n = shift;
  return 1 if $n == 0 || $n ==1;
  return $n * fact($n -1);
}
```

(See Mark Reed's interesting comment about the possible [tail-call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) issue in the original script. More about it at the end of this answer.)

Not the `$sum` values should be less then a threshold, but the kth difference item.
So in `approx_pi` you should use something like this:

```
my $Diff = 1;
while ($Diff > 1e-15) {
    my $p1 = factorial((4 * $k), 1);
    my $p2 = 1103 + (26390 * $k);
    my $p3 = (factorial($k, 1))**4;
    my $p4 = 396**(4 * $k);

    $Diff = ($p1 * $p2) / ($p3 * $p4);
    $sum += $Diff;

    $k++;
}
```

But anyway always recursively calling the `factorial` and calculating the `396 power of 4k` is not effective, so they can be just left off.

```
sub approx_pi {
    my $const = 4900.5 / sqrt(2);

    my $k = 0;
    my $k4 = 0;
    my $F1 = 1;
    my $F4 = 1;
    my $Pd = 396**4;
    my $P2 = 1103;
    my $P4 = 1;
    my $sum = 0;

    while (1) {
        my $Diff = ($F4 * $P2) / ($F1**4 * $P4);
        $sum += $Diff;
        last if $Diff < 1e-15;

        ++$k;
        $k4 += 4;
        $F1 *= $k;
        $F4 *= ($k4 - 3)*($k4 - 2)*($k4 - 1)*$k4;
        $P2 += 26390;
        $P4 *= $Pd;
    }

    return $const / $sum;
}
```

The result is:

```
my pi is: 3.14159265358979
```

I did some measures. `Approx_pi` function was run 1 000 000 times. The fixed original version takes 24 seconds, the other one 5 sec. For me it is somehow interesting that, `$F1**4` is faster than `$F1*$F1*$F1*$F1`.

---

Some words about the factorial. Because of Mark's comment I tried different implementations, to find the fastest solution. 5 000 000 loops were run for different implementations to calculate `15!`:

Recursive version

```
sub rfact;
sub rfact($) {
    return 1 if $_[0] < 2;
    return $_[0] * rfact $_[0] - 1 ;
}
```

46.39 sec

Simple loop version

```
sub lfact($) {
     my $f = 1;
     for(my $i = 2; $i <= $_[0]; ++$i) { $f *= $i }
     return $f;
}
```

16.29 sec

Recursion with call-tail optimization (call `_fact 15,1`):

```
sub _fact($$) {
    return $_[1] if $_[0] < 2;
    @_ = ($_[0] - 1, $_[0] * $_[1]);
    goto &_fact;
}
```

108.15 sec

Recursion with storing intermediate values

```
my @h = (1, 1);
sub hfact;
sub hfact($) {
    return $h[$_[0]] if $_[0] <= $#h;
    return $h[$_[0]] = $_[0] * hfact $_[0] - 1;
}
```

3.87 sec

Loop with storing intermediate values. The speed is the same as previous as only the first time is has to be run.

```
my @h = (1, 1);
sub hlfact($) {
    if ($_[0] > $#h) {
      my $f = $h[-1];
      for (my $i = $#h + 1; $i <= $_[0]; ++$i) { $h[$i] = $f *= $i }
    }
    return $h[$_[0]];
}
```

Comment: or just `return $total if $i < 2;`. Passing the total along in `factorial` is presumably to allow tail-recursion optimization.

Comment: @MarkReed: You may be right, but the `factorial` function is not needed anyway... :)

Comment: @MarkReed: If the "tail-recursion optimization" was in the picture I would recommend a proxy function having one argument and then call a two-argument (even function) internal function. I think it would be more user firendly.

Comment: This is a better response than I expected to get! Thanks for your time, very insightful and gives me a lot to experiment with. :)

Comment: @bladepanthera: You are welcome! I modified a little bit the answer.

Comment: @TrueY, I can see 26390 being added into the equation, but where does it get multiplied by $k, can you point that out?

Comment: @bladepanthera: Value of `$P2` is always equals with `1103 + (26390 * $k);`. So in the next loop only `26390` value has to be added. So its value become `1103 + (26390 * ($k + 1));`.

Comment: @TrueY I think I understand your explanation, but I do not understand it in the code, sorry! 

I'm following `$P2` - to start with it is `1103`; next it gives its value to `$p2` which is fine, then `26390` is added on; I don't see where `$k` is used. Is that not the point where `$k` should be multiplied by the `26390`? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding!

Comment: @bladepanthera: Ok. In the first run of the loop `$k = 0; $P2 = 1103`. In the second loop `$k = 1; $P2 = 1103 + 26390 * 1`. 3rd: `$k = 2; $P2 = 1103 + 26390 * 2` etc. In Nth loop: `$k = <N-1>; $P2 = 1103 + 26390 * <N-1>` I replaced the multiplication with adding `26390` in each loop, which is much "cheaper". Similar done for multiplication. Instead of always calculation the `fact($k)`, I multiple a variable (`$F1`) with `$k`, so ist value will be `fact($k)` in each loop. Again a multiplication is much cheaper, then calculate the `fact($k)` in each loop.

Comment: Ok, It took me writing it out on paper to see it! Thanks again :)

Comment: @MarkReed: thanks for your valuable comment! I dig into it a little bit and I found that in perl 5 call-tail optimization is not implemented, but can be done by setting `@_` and use `goto &factorial`. But this is not the case here. An old [article](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=161611) said the is was planned to be implemented in perl 6 in some basic cases.

Comment: @MarkReed: I added some measures about the call-tail optimization. It is weird, but it seems that in perl 5 the call-tail optimization does not reduce the calculation speed.

Comment: @bladepanthera: I modified the loop. In the last step it is not needed to increment a temporary values, so it just exits the loop as soon as possible.